# How do I check if value already exists in table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been struggling with a "check if e-mail exists-problem" in my database. The whole function is about changing your e-mail address for your account.

I want to check if the e-mail address already exists in my database. I guess you'll know what I'm after if you just check my code:

```
if($_POST["changeemail2"]=="Send request")
{
$newemail=$_POST["newmail"];
$sql="SELECT email FROM tbluser";
$result=$objMysql->query($sql);

while($dbmails = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if(in_array($newmail, $dbmails) && empty($_SESSION["emailerror"]))
    {
    $_SESSION["emailerror"]="That e-mail address<br />is already in use.";
    }
}


if(empty($newemail))
{
    $_SESSION["emailerror"]="You didn't select<br />a new e-mail address";
}


if($_SESSION["emailerror"]=="")
{
    $oldemail=$_SESSION["user"]["email"];
    if($objMysql->sendchangeEmail($oldemail, $newemail))
    {
        $_SESSION["emailsuccess"]="E-mail verification has been sent to your current e-mail.";
        $code="success";
    }
}

}
```

I have tried many different aspects but my brain is just not working right now.

Comment: @Rahil: please do not reformat code just to apply a different coding standard. In general, this might accidentally cover up the error in question, and in any case the choice of coding standards is subjective. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`unique constraint`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html). Try to insert/update the record and catch the exception thrown when the unique constraint is violated. This is the only way to guarantee an unique e-mail adresses; first checking and then updating is prone to concurrency issues since it is possible that someone else updates his/her record to the same value you're trying to set just after you did the check and before updating the record.

Also: learn how to use [`where`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)-clauses. You're now retrieving ALL records, iterating over them etc. which takes unecessarily much resources, takes too long and is just a plain waste. If you want to check for a record matching a criteria you write:

```
Select foo, bar from table where baz = 123
```

Where `baz = 123` is your criterium. Imagine what would happen when you have 500, or even 500,000 records in your current setup. The database would execute your query, gather ALL rows from that database, transfer them to your application where your application would iterate all 500,000 results. Or you ask the DB to do what it's good at (and why you're using it in the first place): Gimme the/all record(s) that match criterium X. You'd get 1 or none records (given the unique constraint): 1 = some record matches your criterium, none = no records exist. Saves transfering and "manually having to look at" 499,999 records ;-)

Comment: The check is not required; the exception that is thrown can easily be caught and THEN be used to display a user-friendly message.

Comment: So, while I believe that the database is *the* Gate Keeper of the data, there are many times in which it is cleaner to take care of the riffraff sooner and to move covering logic forward.

Comment: @user2864740: That's a whole different story (Ajax stuff you're talking about); for that I would implement an `IsUsernameAvailable()` method. But that has nothing to do with the actual question Anen was asking and is, though from a technical viewpoint very much the same, a problem (or user-story or whatever you want to call it) on a whole different level.