# How to stop storing existing username and emails in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, email

I want to stop users from storing existing email addresses and usernames in the database. I tried with the if statement below: if row exists for both username and email then echo statement. Otherwise insert if username and email doesn't exist in the database.

However, it seems to still store data.

```
    $selectUser= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$username'") or die (mysql_error());
    $selectEmail= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$email'") or die (mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($selectUser) > 0) {
        echo 'Wrong Username!';
    }
    if(mysql_num_rows($selectEmail) > 0) {
        echo 'Wrong Email!';
    } 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (username,password,email) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email')") or die (mysql_error());
        echo 'Congrats! You have registed!';
        exit();
```

Comment: You can do it in one statement using the `OR` operator as well as adding an extra variable in your `WHERE` clause. You also need to add a `die();` or `exit;` after your echoes.

Comment: Sidenote: Change `echo 'Congrats! You've registed!';` to `echo "Congrats! You've registed!";` because it will cause a parse error. Or, escape it `echo 'Congrats! You\'ve registed!';`

Comment: Please use PDO. Some people can not give you an advice on top of using the example you've shown.

Comment: +1 for using PDO. You better be doing some serious validation on your $username and $email variables if you're running a raw query like that.

Comment: Use INSERT IGNORE and make email a unique field.

Comment: What you need is a `unique constraint` on the username and email fields. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22427979/215042

Comment: I've used unique constraints already. Somehow it seems to still store even with unique constraints enabled...

Comment: hmm never used PDO, and not sure how it works. I think it's best if I just stick with what I know for now.

Comment: @Martynogea [This can happen to you](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png) +1 for using PDO

Comment: I'll look into PDO or MySQLi later, but for now I'll stick with what I have as I did quite a lot on my other php pages, and also I know nothing about them. I'll manually add in strip lashes, escape string etc for protection for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you insist on using 2 queries, try this. If you feel the need to separate "duplicate Username" and "duplicate Email" error, just get another if {} in there.

```
$selectUser= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$username'") or die (mysql_error());
$selectEmail= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$email'") or die (mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($selectUser) > 0 or mysql_num_rows($selectEmail) > 0) {
    echo 'Duplicate Username or Email!';
} else {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (username,password,email) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email')") or die (mysql_error());
    echo 'Congrats! You\'ve registed!';
    exit();
}
```

Or else, use the 1 query answer from Logan Wayne or PeaceDealer.

EDIT: Separate username and email

```
$selectUser= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$username'") or die (mysql_error());
$selectEmail= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$email'") or die (mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($selectUser) > 0 or mysql_num_rows($selectEmail) > 0) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($selectUser) > 0) {
        echo 'Duplicate Username';
    }
    if(mysql_num_rows($selectEmail) > 0) {
        echo 'Duplicate email';
    }
} else {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (username,password,email) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email')") or die (mysql_error());
    echo 'Congrats! You\'ve registed!';
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I thought about using one single if statement for email and user, but the problem with that is it tells the user that there is duplicate username OR email. Which I don't want. I want to tell them specifically what is taken - to save them time. For example, if username is taken, I don't want to tell both email and username is also taken, it's unhelpful to the client.

Comment: I've edited with the separate username and email solution. Although I recommend using the 1 query approach, it will be easier for your database.

Comment: This works, but I don't want to display two echoes under each other. Do you think I should create another if statement saying if both exist then echo duplicate username AND email?

Comment: use this:

if (user > 0) {
   if (email > 0) { echo "both username and email"; }
   else { echo "username"; }
} else {
   if (email > 0) { echo "email"; }
   else { echo "success"; }
}

code has been trimmed down obviously, but you get the idea

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go. I've asked this question above, but I was wondering if you could give me advice on this:

After every query, is it recommended to add a ' exit() ' function? Because on one of my queries I also call a JS function, and if I use exit it'll exit script before it reaches the JS.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you still execute the insert statement after you echo the error messages. Try this instead:

```
$selectUser= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$username'") or die (mysql_error());
$selectEmail= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$email'") or die (mysql_error());

$error = false;
if(mysql_num_rows($selectUser) > 0) {
    echo 'The username is already taken.';
    $error = true;
}
if(mysql_num_rows($selectEmail) > 0) {
    echo 'The email has already been used by another member.';
    $error = true;
} 
if(!$error) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (username,password,email) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email')") or die (mysql_error());
    echo 'Congrats! You\'ve registed!';
    exit();
}
```

if you do not like the `$error` variable you can do like this instead

```
$selectUser= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$username'") or die (mysql_error());
$selectEmail= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$email'") or die (mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($selectUser) > 0) {
    echo 'The username is already taken.';
} elseif (mysql_num_rows($selectEmail) > 0) {
    echo 'The email has already been used by another member.';
} else {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (username,password,email) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email')") or die (mysql_error());
    echo 'Congrats! You\'ve registed!';
    exit();
}
```

Unrelated to your problem, but very important is that you should validate your input (`$username`, `$password`, and `$email`). You can [use mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) for this (or mysqli_real_escape_string if you are using PHP >= 5.0).

Comment: This `echo 'Congrats! You've registed!';` will cause a parse error. Haven't you noticed OP's syntax highlighting?

Comment: This is still wrong - some of your error are still missing $

Comment: This approach is still vulnerable to concurrency issues; what if the Select turns up 0 records and a split-second later someone else inserts a record with the same values before you get to insert your values? You need `unique constraints` in the database to enforce this. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22427979/215042. Aside many other problems (SQL injection, syntax etc.) the messages are also plain wrong. The username/e-mail address aren't "wrong", they are a **duplicate**. The message should be something like "Sorry, that name is already taken" or something similar, not "Wrong username!".

Comment: I've tried this. It works if username and email exist, but if I use a new username and existing email, it still stores the input. Any idea why it's still storing?

Comment: Because $error is never set to true - note the $ before error

Comment: No I meant I did it even with the $ sign before error and still doesn't work.

Comment: @RobIII although you are correct about the concurrency issues, I do not think that it is the main point of this question (and a discussion of this will make the answer more unclear). The error messages is taken from OP, so please redirect your comment about this to the question instead.

Comment: @MathiasBak: OP starts with "I want to stop users from storing existing email addresses and usernames in the database.". The only way to do that reliably is with a unique constraint. Why bother helping out with the code when it doesn't actually SOLVE his problem in the first place? I don't see what "error messages" you're referring to; there are *none* in the OP.

Comment: I've got a question if anyone can help me out. After every query, is it recommended to add a ' exit() ' function? Because on one of my queries I also call a JS function, and if I use exit it'll exit script before it reaches the JS.

Answer (score 0):

Another example way to do this:

```
$select= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '". $username ."' OR  email = '". $email ."'") or die (mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($select) > 0) {
echo "Username or email taken";
} else {    
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (username,password,email) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email')") or die (mysql_error());
    echo 'Congrats! You\'ve registed!';
}
```

But as the others state, you should really validate the inputs by example escaping the strings.

Comment: I did strip tags on the variables for $username etc. Do you recommend me still escaping strings? Also, I want to specifically state to the user what exists, if I merge the select query they will not know which they inputted exist in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in just one query.

```
$select=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$username' OR email='$email'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($select)==0){

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO members (username,password,email) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email')");

}

else {

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

if($row['username']==$username){
   echo "Error: Existing Username";
}

if($row['email']==$email){
   echo "Error: Existing Email Address";
}

}    /* END OF WHILE LOOP */

}    /* END OF ELSE */
```

And please use the latest MySQLi.